# Poor performance on MNIST digit recognition data set

Tags: r, machine-learning, pca, mnist

I have been playing around with the MNIST digit recognition dataset and I am kind of stuck. I read through some research papers and implemented what all I understood. Basically what I  did was that I first created my training set and cross-validation sets for evaluating my classifier, then I ran PCA on both my test and train set and after that I used KNN and SVM to perform the classification task. The main problem I am facing is that should I run PCA on all of the set and then separate my training set and cross validation set or separate them and then run PCA individually on the cross-validation test and training sets. I apologize for asking the things that I have already tried because I have tried out both the scenarios, in the first case my classifier performs brilliantly, because I guess PCA uses the test data set while creating the principle components which tweaks my results and is probably the reason for bias in my model, in the other case the performance is round about 20% to 30% which is very low. So I am kind of stuck how should I refine my model, any help and guidance is highly appreciated, I have pasted my code below for reference.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(e1071)
library(ElemStatLearn)
library(plyr)
library(class)

import.csv <- function(filename){
  return(read.csv(filename, sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

train.data <- import.csv("train.csv")
test.data <- train.data[30001:32000,]
train.data <- train.data[1:6000,]

#Performing PCA on the dataset to reduce the dimensionality of the data

get_PCA <- function(dataset){
  dataset.features <- dataset[,!(colnames(dataset) %in% c("label"))]
  features.unit.variance <- names(dataset[, sapply(dataset, function(v) var(v, na.rm=TRUE)==0)])
  dataset.features <- dataset[,!(colnames(dataset) %in% features.unit.variance)]
  pr.comp <- prcomp(dataset.features, retx = T, center = T, scale = T)
  #finding the total variance contained in the principal components
  prin_comp <- summary(pr.comp)
  prin_comp.sdev <- data.frame(prin_comp$sdev)
  #print(paste0("%age of variance contained = ", sum(prin_comp.sdev[1:500,])/sum(prin_comp.sdev)))
  screeplot(pr.comp, type = "lines", main = "Principal Components")
  num.of.comp = 50
  red.dataset <- prin_comp$x
  red.dataset <- red.dataset[,1:num.of.comp]
  red.dataset <- data.frame(red.dataset)
  return(red.dataset)
}

#Perform k-fold cross validation 

do_cv_class <- function(df, k, classifier){
  num_of_nn = gsub("[^[:digit:]]","",classifier)
  classifier = gsub("[[:digit:]]","",classifier)
  if(num_of_nn == "")
  {
    classifier = c("get_pred_",classifier)
  }
  else
  {
    classifier = c("get_pred_k",classifier)
    num_of_nn = as.numeric(num_of_nn)
  }
  classifier = paste(classifier,collapse = "")
  func_name <- classifier
  output = vector()
  size_distr = c()
  n = nrow(df)
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    a = 1 + (((i-1) * n)%/%k)
    b = ((i*n)%/%k)
    size_distr = append(size_distr, b - a + 1)
  }

  row_num = 1:n
  sampling = list()
  for(i in 1:k)
  {
    s = sample(row_num,size_distr)
    sampling[[i]] = s
    row_num = setdiff(row_num,s)
  }
  prediction.df = data.frame()
  outcome.list = list()

  for(i in 1:k)
  {
    testSample = sampling[[i]]
    train_set = df[-testSample,]
    test_set = df[testSample,]    

    if(num_of_nn == "")
    {
      classifier = match.fun(classifier)
      result = classifier(train_set,test_set)
      confusion.matrix <- table(pred = result, true = test_set$label)
      accuracy <- sum(diag(confusion.matrix)*100)/sum(confusion.matrix)
      print(confusion.matrix)
      outcome <- list(sample_ID = i, Accuracy = accuracy)
      outcome.list <- rbind(outcome.list, outcome)
    }
    else
    {

      classifier = match.fun(classifier)
      result = classifier(train_set,test_set)
      print(class(result))
      confusion.matrix <- table(pred = result, true = test_set$label)
      accuracy <- sum(diag(confusion.matrix)*100)/sum(confusion.matrix)
      print(confusion.matrix)
      outcome <- list(sample_ID = i, Accuracy = accuracy)
      outcome.list <- rbind(outcome.list, outcome)
    }
  }
  return(outcome.list)
}

#Support Vector Machines with linear kernel

get_pred_svm <- function(train, test){
  digit.class.train <- as.factor(train$label)
  train.features <- train[,-train$label]
  test.features <- test[,-test$label]
  svm.model <- svm(train.features, digit.class.train, cost = 10, gamma =  0.0001, kernel = "radial")
  svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, test.features)
  return(svm.pred)
}

#KNN model
get_pred_knn <- function(train,test){
  digit.class.train <- as.factor(train$label)
  train.features <- train[,!colnames(train) %in% "label"]
  test.features <- test[,!colnames(train) %in% "label"]
  knn.model <- knn(train.features, test.features, digit.class.train)
  return(knn.model)
}
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of PCA as a transformation you apply to your data. You want two things to hold:

1. Since the test set mimics a "real-world" situation where you get samples you didn't see before, you cannot use the test set for anything but evaluation of the classifier.
2. You need to apply the same transformation to all samples.

Therefore, you need to apply PCA to the training set, keep the transformation data, which is two pieces of information:

1. The mean you subtracted from the samples in order to centralize them.
2. The transformation matrix, that is the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix

and apply the same transformation to the test set.

Comment: I am so thankful to u for helping me out because I got an accuracy of 96.87% which was amazing, I am sorry for not voting up because it keep saying that I need to have a reputation of 15 to do that.

Comment: Very late to this conversation, but it is generally accepted that one can use the test set data to construct transformations of the data *as long as you only use the predictors*. That is, if I want to predict Y from X, and I have X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, people generally don't care if you use (X_train, X_test, Y_train) to create a classifier. For example, this is what Radford Neal did when he won the 2003 NIPS feature selection challenge. So, in this case, it is fine to use the test set data to do the PCA. Using Y_test is the big no-no.